# Alter Gdal_Grid output cellsize

Tags: gdal, cell-size, gdal-grid

I have a shapefile containing xyz bathymetry points.

I've been using ArcGIS Pro `Point to Raster` tool where I have specified:

```
Input: input.shp
Value Field: Z
Output: output.tiff
Cell Assignment: Minimum
Cellsize: 2
```

I am now trying to find the equivalent tool in GDAL, which I think is `gdal_grid`.

I have altered the outsize as 2 which I assumed was the same as ArcGIS cellsize, but I am getting an entirely black output raster. See code below that I am trying:

```
gdal_grid -zfield Z[m] -a minimum:radius1=0.0:radius2=0.0:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -outsize <2 2> input.shp output.tiff
```

Can anyone help me replicate what I am doing in ArcGIS Pro, but in GDAL so that I can compare results?

Comment: Read again https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html about target resolution and target size. You have created a very small raster with 2x2=4 pixels.

Comment: It's in the doc `-tr xres yres` https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#cmdoption-gdal_grid-tr

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not quite sure going by the documentation

Comment: Is your problem still the size or that the result appears black? Use `-outsize 2000 2000` as a first aid for getting more pixels. The `< >` signs in the documentation are placeholders, I am not sure if you kept them or not but they do not belong to the final command.

Comment: @user30184 even with ```-outsize 2000 2000``` I'm getting an all black result. And, no I wasn't using the ```< >``` signs

Comment: How do you study your image? The full rate of Float32 is very large and if your Z values are heights they are all pretty close to the black end of the range. Have you checked the histogram, or does you viewer support min/max histogram stretch?